# Dynamic padding in css

Tags: css

Given I have an outer and innner div, where the size of the outer div is fixed (border-size) but the size of the inner div is unknown.
Is there a way to give padding to the outer div so the inner div is centered within? (using css/scss)

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  width: 50;
  height: 40;
  ...
}
.inner {
  width: ? // <50
  width: ? // <40
}
```

Comment: Have you tried flexbox? Easiest way to center an element on another that I know of

Answer (score 0):

use display: flex in outer div

check this out:

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background:yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inner {
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  Hey There I am at centre.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For simple, reliable results, you want to use flex box. Use the following on your parent element:

```
display: flex
```

If your goal is center an element, vertically and horizontally within their parent element, you would apply the following rules to the parent element as well:

```
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

**Why the two additional properties?**

One centers on the horizontal axis, the other the vertical. By default a flex container (the parent element) treats the elements as a row, thereby the primary axis is horizontal. A row.

**justify-content** affects the *primary axis*.

**align-items** affects the *secondary axis*.

All said and done, you're turning the parent element into a *flex container* and telling it to center child elements both vertically and horizontally.

Make sure you apply widths and heights to all relevant elements and you're in business!